# Remember the state of bottomNavigation bar when back to a page flutter

Tags: flutter, router, bottomnavigationview

In `main_activity.dart`, there has 4 bottom navigation bar, named A,B,C and D.

**main_activity.dart**

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const ROUTE = '/mainPage';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 2;
  final _tabs = [
    A(),
    B(),
    C(),
    D(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: _tabs[_selectedIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          items: [
           ...
          ],
          onTap: (index) => setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          }),
        ),
      ),
       onWillPop: () => _requestPop(context),
    );
  }
}
```

Initially it will open page in tab C. When I click tab B, it will show B page which contains a floating action button. When floating action button is clicked, it will call `add_B.dart`. My problem is when I click the back button in `add_B.dart`, it will back to `main_activity` and open tab C page. How can I make it open tab B page instead?

**add_B.dart**

```
onWillPop: (){
        _backToPreviousPage(context);
      },

 void _backToPreviousPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MainPage.ROUTE);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `global.dart` file and in it declare `int _selectedIndex = 2;`
and import the file whenever you use it if you set `_selectedIndex` to a certain value the value is saved with you all over the app.

Comment: let say I click the back button in `add_B.dart`. How can I load tab B state?

Comment: before you navigate to the next page set _selectedIndex  to the desired index

Comment: yes, I have done that. `onTap: (index) => setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          }),`

Comment: But when I back from add_B, it load the third tab page @@

Comment: Is it because  `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MainPage.ROUTE);` ?

Comment: try to pass _selectedIndex = 1; statically

Comment: how can I pass ? Thanks

Comment: onWillPop: () { 
//here
_requestPop(context);}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201277/discussion-between-john-joe-and-mohamed-adel).